# Android - How to screen pin other apps programmatically?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-screen-pinning

I am working on app which has device owner privileges, i have to implement the "Screen Pinning" feature which introduced is in Android Lollipop. According to Developer Blog we can pin any app programmatically using `Activity.startLockTask()` and unpinned using `Activity.stoplockTask()`.

But according to my requirements i want to Screen Pin other apps programmatically.

Please let me know if it is possible. If yes then how? Thank you!

Comment: any answers/suggestions??...anybody???

Comment: Almost all questions of the tag [android-screen-pinning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-screen-pinning?sort=newest) are similiar to yours. In short: You can't screen pin 3rd party apps.

Comment: @oneworld Yes you can there is an app Touch Lock Lite, it does somehow

Comment: @Duna Where did you get that information from? link?

Comment: @OneWorld Check this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kidscrape.touchlock.lite&hl=en is doing pinning to other apps

Comment: @Duna Well, there are other methods to achive blocking/enforcing 3rd party apps. But I am not convinced that `Activity.startLockTask()` is involved there.

Comment: @OneWorld Could you point some link/hint to achieve enforcing pinning of other apps? Just want ti dig into

Comment: If you target only Samsung devices, you could pay 5-8 USD to use a single-app kiosk mode via KNOX

Comment: If you want an all in one solution, you can pay (quite a lot) and use https://www.42gears.com/products/surelock/surelock-android/

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No is the answer. I guess you are wondering why? You cannot do pinning on 3rd party apps but you can have your own activity with a transparent theme and more important showing as `<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>` - this will not make your players being paused(YouTube or Netflix) then you can do screen pinning to your own transparent activity shown as window.

On long use (1) this theme in the activity:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

(2) Have a foreground service that starts this activity at time as you want(letting time to open other app)

(3) Do in onResume activity `startLockTask();`

That easy!